# What is the exact assumption behind OW-CPA of NTRU?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, ntru

As shown in [this](https://users.monash.edu.au/%7Erste/NTRU_survey.pdf) paper the IND-CPA of NTRU is based on both the decision key cracking problem and the decision ciphertext cracking problem. However, I often see claims (such as in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.05413.pdf) paper) that the OW-CPA of NTRU only relies on decision key cracking problem. I don't see a way to prove this.

Suppose that in the OW-CPA game we replace the key generation step with uniform sampling, it is not apparent to me that the game cannot be won with non-negligible probability. In that case I do not see a way to build a distinguisher to break decision key cracking problem. So what is the exact assumption on which OW-CPA of NTRU is based?